# vaiShNava-s and food

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, food

Is there a specific injunction in vaiShNava Agama-s or purANa-s to the effect that food should be consumed only after it is offered to viShNu?

As far as brAhmaNa-s are concerned, it is clear from the sUtra-s that they should consume only food

- offered to agni and shrotriya in case of gRhasthAshrama
- guru or his representative or agni in case of brahmacharya.

Such a rule would explain the sectarian practice of offering vaishvadeva only from food first offered to viShNu.

PS:‌nityakarma texts by shrI rAmAnuja (भगवद्भाष्यकारैर्-विरचित-[नित्यग्रन्थे](https://archive.org/stream/NityaGranthaOfRamanujaWithVrittiOfRambhadracharyaN.S.SanskritAcademyMelkote/Nitya%20Grantha%20of%20Ramanuja%20with%20Vritti%20of%20Rambhadracharya%20N.S.%20Sanskrit%20Academy%20Melkote#page/n37/mode/2up) भगवदाराधनान्तर्गत-भोज्यासनविधौ २१३-तम खण्डे "अर्हणपूर्वकं हविर् निवेदयेत्" इति सूचितम् अस्ति।) and [madhva](https://archive.org/stream/AhnikaKaustubhaOfSrinivasaTirthaCommentaryOnSadacharaSmritiOfMadhvacharyaEditorialBoard/Ahnika%20Kaustubha%20Of%20Srinivasa%20Tirtha%20Commentary%20on%20Sadachara%20Smriti%20of%20Madhvacharya%20%20Editorial%20Board#page/n41/mode/2up) clearly specify such rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this practice arises from the verse in ***Vishnu Purana*** which discusses the quality of food, once it is 'eaten'(?) by the Lord. The practice therefore has carried on since millennia.

> **naivedyam jagadisasya 
>  anna-panadikam ca yat
>
>   bhaksyabhaksya-vicaras ca
>  nasti tad-bhaksane dvijah**
>
> **brahmavan-nirvikaram hi
>  yatha visnus tathaiva tat
>  vikaram ye
>   prakurvanti
>  bhaksane tad dvijatayah**
>
> **kustha-vyadhi-samayuktah
>  putra-dara-vivarjitah
>  nirayam yanti
>   te vipras
>  tasman navartate punah**
>
> "O brahmanas, in the eating of food such as rice and water, etc.,
>   which has been tasted by the Lord of the universe [Vishnu obviously, since this is 
>   Vishnu Purana] there is
>   no consideration of whether it is edible in inedible. Just as Lord
>   Vishnu is spiritual and is not subject to mundane transformation, so in
>   the same way His prasada is spiritual and eternal. Those
>   brahmanas, who consider that in the eating of Vishnu-prasada there is
>   some mundane transformation of its spiritual qualities and thus it can
>   become contaminated by contact with someone's mouth or hands, become
>   afflicted with leprosy, become bereft of their sons and wife, and go
>   to hell, never again to return from that place."

This is supported by ***Srimad Bhagavatam***, which is said to be one the greatest book for the Vaishnavas, especially Gaudiya Vaishnavas who consider it even higher than Vishnu Purana, only second to Bhagavad Gita.

> **shadbhir masopavasais tu 
>  yat phalam parikirtitam
>  vishnor naivedya-sikthannam
>  bhunjatam tat kalau yuge**
>
> "In Kali-yuga they who eat Lord Vishnu's prasadam attain the same
>   result said to be gained by fasting for six months."

Comment: The answer which my acharyadeva mentioned to me is that the practice of taking prasadam comes from these two sources. I have no other information, besides this.

Comment: @vishvAsvAsuki What made you change the comment?

Comment: I reread the question and realized that your answer was appropriate (but had not seen your reply). Hence I changed the comment.